# UWP Automated build error: Your project is not referencing the "UAP,Version=v10.0.10240" framework

Tags: uwp, nuget, azure-devops, project.json

I upgraded my `Nuget` version on my UWP automated build from `V3.5.0` to `V4.0.0`

After doing so my `UWP` build I got the following error:

> error : Your project is not referencing the "UAP,Version=v10.0.10240"
>   framework. Add a reference to "UAP,Version=v10.0.10240" in the
>   "frameworks" section of your project.json, and then re-run NuGet
>   restore.

I'm not sure how to add a reference to that `UAP,Version=v10.0.10240` in my `project.json`

My `project.json` file looks like so:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.3.3",
    "Xamarin.Forms": "2.3.4.247"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "uap10.0": {}
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-arm": {},
    "win10-arm-aot": {},
    "win10-x86": {},
    "win10-x86-aot": {},
    "win10-x64": {},
    "win10-x64-aot": {}
  }
}
```

I would have presumed that the `uap.10.0` was sufficient.

Is there another framework I need to add?

Comment: Try to use[nuget 4.1](https://dist.nuget.org/index.html) and check the result (Specify NuGet.exe in Nuget task 0.*). Related issue: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4532 and https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4515

Comment: @starain-MSFT I tried installing the [Nuget.CommandLine Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.CommandLine/) and then specifying the path to that, but then realised using a `Nuget` package to run `Nuget` probably isnt going to work. Have you got a way of installing `Nuget 4.1`? Currently the VSTS task only goes up to `4.0.0`

Comment: `Nuget 3.5.0` had an error where I needed `msbuild 12` installed hence why I upgraded

Comment: I actually ended up installing `VS2015` and downgrading to `3.5.0` if you've got any good solutions to using a custom nuget version let me know and I'll try it out. Obviously if you are using a cloud vm you wont be lucky enough to have access

Comment: 1. Download nuget 4.1 2. Add it to source control or share folder 3. Add Nuget task 4. Change 2.* to 0.* 5. Expand Advance section 6. Specify NuGet.exe path

Comment: On the other hand, is it a Visual Studio 2015 project? Could you reproduce this issue with a new project?

Comment: There is NuGet Tool Installer task in Tool category, you can add it before NuGet restore task. The Universal Windows Platform build template uses it. (create build definition=> Select Universal Windows Platform template). On the other hand, I can't reproduce this issue with UWP app (created via vs 2015), can you share a simple project on the OneDrive?

Answer (score 2):

In my case I've solved running restore from Visual Studio Command Prompt:

```
msbuild /t:restore path-to-solution-file.sln
```